# React JS Вставить код символа в JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
function format(str) {

  return str.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, "$1&#x202F*;");
}
```

Подскажите как правильно заменять в строке паттерн кодом определенного символа. "$1  " - не пойму где здесь ошибка, в верстку вместо короткого пробела вставляется сам код символа. (*звездочку поставил специально чтобы корректно отобразился код символа в вопросе*)
результат работы этого метода вставляю в JSX.

```
<div>{format('123123123')}</div>
```

В верстке получаю 123&#x202F*;123&#x202F*;123

Comment: а в чем проблема, сначала получить этот символ в переменную, а потом его добавить в строку ?

Comment: А зачем вставлять код если можно вставить символ? `$1\u202f`

Comment: https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#html-entities